# JS Compatible Haxe Promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, haxe

Are [any of the Haxe Promise libraries](http://blog.zame-dev.org/why-hxbolts/) compatible with standard ES6 promises.  The only one that mentions compatibility with Promise/A+ is [Redhawk](https://github.com/andywhite37/redhawk), which is relatively new and doesn't explicity state that it can be used from JS.  Everything else is either silent on the subject or states that it doesn't **follow** the Promise/A+ standard but they don't say it's incompatible either.

I'm using them in the context of a cross-platform library, so information on support for other language's native promise or async handling is welcome.

Answer (score 5):

I'm the creator of Redhawk.  It is not completely in-line with the Promise/A+ spec, and there is not currently a hook to coerce native JS Promises to redhawk promises, but I think that would be fairly easy to make.  I'll create an issue to look into that.

I replied to your issue in redhawk.  If you just need native JS promises, you can always use the Haxe std lib extern https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxe/blob/development/std/js/Promise.hx